# How to use IOptions pattern in Program.cs in .NET6, before builder.build()?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-6.0

Using the options pattern in .NET6, I can get access to some config values as follows:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiConfiguration>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(ApiConfiguration.Api));

var app = builder.Build();

var options = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApiConfiguration>>().Value;
```

However, I would like to get the Options **before builder.Build()**, so I can use the appSettings values when adding some Services to the ServiceCollections.

I haven't been able to find it anywhere yet, so I am wondering if it is even possible (and how ofcourse :D )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the default DI container services can't be resolved before it is built and building the container multiple times is not a recommended approach (for multiple reasons). If you need settings before the application is built you can access them without the options pattern:

```cs
var settings = builder.Configuration
    .GetSection(ApiConfiguration.Api)
    .Get<ApiConfiguration>();
```

Answer (score 2):

> so I can use the appSettings values when adding some Services to the ServiceCollections.

This sounds wrong to me as `IOptions` are part of DI container and can be injected in the constructor.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<Service>();

...

public class Service
{
    private readonly ApiConfiguration myOptions;
    
    public Service(IOptions<ApiConfiguration> options)
    {
        myOptions = options.Value;
    }
}
```

If your class can't rely on `IOptions` like in the example below

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly ApiConfiguration myOptions;
    
    public Service(ApiConfiguration options)
    {
        myOptions = options;
    }
}
```

, use a factory method instead:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ApiConfiguration>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApiConfiguration>>().Value);
builder.Services.AddScoped<Service>();
```

OR

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<Service>(sp => new Service(sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApiConfiguration>>().Value));
```

Comment: I highly suspect that OP needed options to configure something (JWT settings, database context settings, etc.) before `builder.Build()` is called, so it is too early to use DI here.